# RxAndroidBle how to do write to ble device correctly?

Tags: rxandroidble

Hi i am trying to build my first app with RxJava and BLE and i have a question: I  made a wite(byte b) method in singletone class(that i use for connection, notifications, etc..). So now if i want to write data to BLE device i call this method. I need to do this a lot  from different parts of code. I am very new to RxJava concept, and i feel like i am doing wrong.
Current solution:

```
public void write(byte[] b) {

        if (isConnected()) {
            connectionObservable
                    .flatMap(rxBleConnection -> rxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic(characteristicUuid, b))
                    .subscribe(bytes -> {
                        onWriteSuccess(bytes);
                    }, this::onWriteFailure);
        }

    }
```

I feel like i need to do something like that, but i dont know how:

```
 protected static final BlockingQueue<byte[]> TxQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(32);

 public void write(byte[] b) {

       TxQueue.add(bytes);

    }
```

And call this only once during connection to device:

```
connectionObservable
                    .flatMap(rxBleConnection ->     rxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic(characteristicUuid, TxQueue.take))
                    .subscribe(bytes -> {
                        onWriteSuccess(bytes);
                    }, this::onWriteFailure);
```

Thanks for an answer!

Comment: Why do you want a `TxQueue` for?

Comment: I am not very good with Rx Concept. So before i used queue in android service to add all data to it,  and  while(true) loop to take the data from this queue to send

Comment: Just want to know my first solution is OK?

Answer (score 0):

Your first solution will work just fine.

The RxAndroidBle library is handling queueing of the commands for you so the only thing you need to do is to `subscribe()` to `RxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic()`.

There is also similar questions already on Stackoverflow:
[RxAndroidBle keeping a persistant connection + Write/Notification handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38902913/rxandroidble-keeping-a-persistant-connection-write-notification-handling)

Best Regards