# rxandroidble: ble device disconnected for long duration: App goes to sleep

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, rxandroidble

I am using rxandroidble using autoconnect = true to continuously monitor data from a sensor. The app continuously scans for sensors it has previously connected to.

The data monitoring and scanning for sensors should continue all night, even if the phone is not connected to a power source.

If a sensor is connected in the evening, the app will stay connected all night, even if it disconnects momentarily.

However, if a sensor is disconnected for 6 hours during the night (because I pulled the sensor's battery), and then I reconnect the sensor battery in the morning, the phone does not appear to reconnect to the sensor.

I am constantly scanning every 8 seconds for new sensors in an Android service, but its not a WakefulService, nor is it started by a WakefulIntent. Should it be?

Any idea what could be going on? Is rxandroidble designed to keep scanning for sensors in this situation (ble device connects, goes out of range for 8 hours, then comes back into range)? 
Or do i need to manually attempt reconnect after disconnect, and then rxandroid will continually attempt to reconnect.

Here is my scan code:

```
    public boolean scanForDevices(boolean on){


    if(on){
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "scanForDevices: bluetooth not enabled, scan failed" );
            return false; // bluetooth disabled
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

            if (TheApplication.getInstance().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.e(TAG, "scanForDevices: ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission not granted, scan failed" );
                return false; // App doesn't have permission granted
            }
        }

        if (isScanning()) {
            scanSubscription.unsubscribe();
        } else {

            scanSubscription = RxBleClientSingleton.getInstance().getRxBleClient().scanBleDevices()
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .doOnError(this::onScanFailure)
                    .doOnUnsubscribe(this::clearSubscription)
                    .subscribe(this::onScanResult, this::onScanFailure);


            //Ensure we won't Scan forever (save battery)
            if (EnablePeriodicScan == true) {
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (isScanning())
                            scanForDevices(false);
                    }
                }, 4000);
            }

        }
    }else{
        //Turn scanning off
        if(isScanning()){
            scanSubscription.unsubscribe();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

and here is my connect code:

```
public void RxBleConnect() {



    autoConnectSetting = true;



    if (false == sensorConnectionState.equals(SensorConnectionState.Disconnected)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "RxBleConnect: cannot connect, #" + allowReconnect + " : " + macAddress + " isn't disconnected, currently in " + sensorConnectionState.toString() );

        if ((sensorConnectionState.equals(SensorConnectionState.Connected)) &&  (allowReconnect > 15)) { /// reached our limit even though we are connected?
            allowReconnect = 0; // reset count
            Disconnect(); // disconnect sensor.
            Log.d(TAG, "RxBleConnect: someone keeps knocking, appears that " + macAddress + " isn't as connected as we thought.");
        }
        allowReconnect ++;

        return; // dont reattempt connection if already attempting to connect
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "RxBleConnect: connecting to sensor....");

    SystemClock.sleep(400);


    connectionObservable  =
            bleDevice.establishConnection(TheApplication.getInstance(), autoConnectSetting)

            .compose(new ConnectionSharingAdapter())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())


            .doOnUnsubscribe(this::RxBleDisconnect)
            .takeUntil(disconnectTriggerSubject)
            .doOnError(throwable -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "rxBleConnection doOnError: " + throwable);
                Disconnect(); // triggerDisconnect();
            });



    connectionSubscription = connectionObservable
            .flatMap(RxBleConnection::discoverServices)
            .subscribe(this::RxBleOnConnectionReceived, this::RxBleOnConnectionFailure);



}
```

If the connection state changes to disconnect, I don't attempt reconnect manually; either scanning or autoconnect should take care of this issue right?

I have turned off "App Optimization" aka Doze mode for the app in android battery settings, but I don't know if that is doing anything.

> > > > EDIT 1:
> > > >         Here are my logs.... we connect ok the first time, then we attempt connecting, then we immediately disconnect:

```
>>> FIRST CONNECTION <<<
12-09 21:23:46.904 8992-8992/appName D/PeripheralManager: RxBleConnect: connecting to sensor...., auto connect = false
onConnectionStateChange newState=2 status=0
12-09 21:23:09.298 8992-8992/appName D/PeripheralManager: onConnectionStateChange: new state RxBleConnectionState{CONNECTED}
12-09 21:23:46.831 8992-9004/appName D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=8 clientIf=5 device=E0:CF:8D:98:69:6A
12-09 21:23:46.832 8992-9004/appName D/RxBle#BluetoothGatt: onConnectionStateChange newState=0 status=8
12-09 21:23:46.897 8992-8992/appName D/PeripheralManager: onConnectionStateChange: new state RxBleConnectionState{DISCONNECTED}
12-09 21:23:46.897 8992-8992/appName D/Peripheral Manager: setConnectionState: Set e0:cf:8d:98:69:6a connection state to Disconnected
12-09 21:23:46.898 8992-8992/appName E/PeripheralManager: ### sendDisconnectNotification: mid = 2698601

>>> ATTEMPT RECONNECT HERE <<<<
12-09 21:23:46.904 8992-8992/appName D/PeripheralManager: RxBleConnect: connecting to sensor...., auto connect = true
12-09 21:23:46.915 8992-9004/appName D/RxBle#Radio:   QUEUED RxBleRadioOperationDisconnect(250971465)
12-09 21:23:46.916 8992-9070/appName D/RxBle#Radio:  STARTED RxBleRadioOperationDisconnect(250971465)
12-09 21:23:46.922 8992-9004/appName D/BluetoothGatt: setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: f8c00003-159f-11e6-92f5-0002a5d5c51b enable: false
12-09 21:23:46.928 8992-9004/appName D/RxBle#Radio:   QUEUED RxBleRadioOperationDescriptorWrite(49261423)
12-09 21:23:47.306 8992-8992/appName D/RxBle#Radio:   QUEUED RxBleRadioOperationConnect(200794900)
12-09 21:23:47.316 8992-8992/appName D/PeripheralManager: onConnectionStateChange: new state RxBleConnectionState{CONNECTING}
12-09 21:23:47.316 8992-8992/appName D/Peripheral Manager: setConnectionState: Set e0:cf:8d:98:69:6a connection state to Connecting…
12-09 21:23:47.340 8992-8992/appName D/BluetoothManager: getConnectionState()
12-09 21:23:47.340 8992-8992/appName D/BluetoothManager: getConnectedDevices
12-09 21:23:47.347 8992-9070/appName D/RxBle#Radio: FINISHED RxBleRadioOperationDisconnect(250971465)
12-09 21:23:47.348 8992-9070/appName D/RxBle#Radio:  STARTED RxBleRadioOperationDescriptorWrite(49261423)
12-09 21:23:47.348 8992-8992/appName D/PeripheralManager: rxBleConnection doOnError: BleGattException{status=8, bleGattOperation=BleGattOperation{description='CONNECTION_STATE'}}
12-09 21:23:47.355 8992-8992/appName D/PeripheralManager: observeConnectionStateChanges FINISHED
12-09 21:23:47.355 8992-8992/appName D/PeripheralManager: rxBleConnection doOnError: BleGattException{status=8, bleGattOperation=BleGattOperation{description='CONNECTION_STATE'}}
```

Thanks!

> > > > 2nd EDIT:

Code for consuming

private void RxBleOnConnectionReceived(RxBleDeviceServices services) {
        // discover services

```
    connectionsCount ++;

    Log.d(TAG, "RxBleOnConnectionReceived: Discovered services");


    setConnectionState(SensorConnectionState.Connected);

    try {



    connectionSubscription = connectionObservable
            .flatMap(rxBleConnection -> rxBleConnection.setupNotification(BluetoothLeUart.RX_UUID))
            .doOnError(throwable -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "RxBleOnConnectionReceived setupNotification doOnError: " + throwable);
                Disconnect(); 
            })
            .doOnNext(notificationObservable -> {
                // Notification has been set up
            })
            .flatMap(notificationObservable -> notificationObservable) // <-- Notification has been set up, now observe value changes.
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnError(throwable -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "RxBleOnConnectionReceived doOnError: " + throwable);
            })
            .subscribe(
                    bytes -> {
                        // Given characteristic has been changes, here is the value.
                    processReceivedMessage(bytes);

                    },
                    throwable -> {
                        /*handle throwable*/

                        Log.e(TAG, "RxBleOnConnectionReceived: processReceivedMessage： " + throwable );
                    }
            );
```

Comment: hi i am facing this exception right now for more than 2 day your help is more appreciated . can you send the snippet or code .

Answer (score 1):

There are several questions you have asked:

- What service to use while the phone enters a doze mode?

The is a good question on stackoverflow already available. For instance here: [How does doze mode affect background/foreground services, with/without partial/full wakelocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37869201/how-does-doze-mode-affect-background-foreground-services-with-without-partial-f) There is also an issue in Cordova Plugin github page about using the BLE during doze: https://github.com/thaliproject/Thali_CordovaPlugin/issues/413

- Is `RxAndroidBle` supposed to reconnect automatically if the device looses connection?

No. After the connection has ended (wether it was started using `autoconnect` = true or false) it has to be reestablished by calling `RxBleDevice.establishConnection` again.
From the library description:

> Auto connect
>
> (...)
>
> Auto connect concept may be misleading at first glance. With the
>   autoconnect flag set to false the connection will end up with an error
>   if a BLE device is not advertising when the
>   RxBleDevice#establishConnection method is called. From platform to
>   platform timeout after which the error is emitted differs, but in
>   general it is rather tens of seconds than single seconds.
>
> Setting the auto connect flag to true allows you to wait until the BLE
>   device becomes discoverable. The RxBleConnection instance won't be
>   emitted until the connection is fully set up. From experience it also
>   handles acquiring wake locks, so it's safe to assume that your Android
>   device will be woken up after the connection has been established -
>   but it is not a documented feature and may change in the future system
>   releases.

- Will scanning or connecting with `autoconnect = true` take care of reconnecting?

It is hard to reason about what is triggering the `scanForDevices()` function but it looks like it automatically finishes after 4 seconds. If the scanning is on and the user would call `scanForDevices(true)` the scanning would be stopped anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much. So does EstablishConnection continuously try to connect until it finds that device? or does it fail after a quick timeout? I guess ill try and report back unless you have a test result.

And yes, scanForDevices is called after rxble initialization, and runs every 8 seconds, for a duration of 4 seconds. But i believe that it will be prevented from doing anything when the app enters deep sleep...

Comment: I have edited the answer. Short story: `autoconnect = false` -> timeout after 30 seconds if device is not available, `autoconnect = true` -> no timeout until the device will be available.

From here: https://github.com/thaliproject/Thali_CordovaPlugin/issues/413 you can read about possible scenarios with doze. Apparently it doesn't change much if the service is running.

Comment: What response? If I didn't answer your question - please clarify the them for me or describe what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, my first SO post...
As for my issue, I'm having instant autoconnect failure ....

My code for Rxbleconnect is above.

If I  set autoconnect setting to true, the first connect succeeds, but then after the first DISconnect, if i try to connect again, RxAndroidBle immediately disconnects... it appears it is immediately entering the .doOnUnsubscribe portion of my establishConnection call... 

Any idea why? How do I ensure there is a subscriber?
Is this because I separated the connectionObservable and the connectionSubscription into separate calls? (see code above)
 
Thanks!

Comment: If you use `Subscriber` subclass for consuming events then keep in mind that they are stateful. If one `Subscriber` recieves `onCompleted()` or `onError()` it will not work when subscribing again. It has to be a new `Subscriber`. Secondly `Observable` that is result of `RxBleDevice.establishConnection()` is meant to be used one time only. After it will disconnect or error another call to `RxBleDevice.establishConnection()` is needed.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt replies.
I am not using a Subscriber subclass.
I'm calling subscribe after I figure out what services the device provides...
See 2nd Edit above for the code...

My situation is a lot like the one in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38902913/rxandroidble-keeping-a-persistant-connection-write-notification-handling

But i think my knowledge of rxjava is not sufficient. 
I wish there was a full reference design for this type of app for the library.... persistant IoT connections are more and more popular. I know that is quite a lot to ask so I wouldnt expect it..

Comment: I will think of a more complicated example with sustaining the connection and handling multiple (asynchronous) events during the time. Every use-case is different and without full knowledge of yours I cannot really help. As for now I can only advice you to extend your knowledge of rxJava - it will definitely benefit you.