# Write/Notification handling with rxandroidble

Tags: java, android, rx-java2, rxandroidble

I am trying to implement this example of write/notification handling ([Using RxAndroidBle, how do I subscribe to responses from writing to a characteristic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41134595/using-rxandroidble-how-do-i-subscribe-to-responses-from-writing-to-a-characteri/41140523#41140523)).

```
connectionObservable
                    .flatMap((Function<RxBleConnection, Observable<Observable<byte[]>>>)
                            (RxBleConnection rxBleConnection) -> {
                                return rxBleConnection.setupNotification(TX_CHAR_UUID);
                            },
                            (BiFunction<RxBleConnection, Observable<byte[]>, Observable<byte[]>>)
                                    (rxBleConnection, apScanDataNotificationObservable) -> {
                                        return Observable.combineLatest(
                                                rxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic(RX_CHAR_UUID, getInputBytes()),
                                                apScanDataNotificationObservable.first(),
                                                new BiFunction<byte[], byte[], byte[]>() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public byte[] apply(byte[] writtenBytes, byte[] responseBytes) throws Exception {
                                                        return responseBytes;
                                                    }
                                                }
                                        );
                                    }
                    ).flatMap(new Function<Observable<byte[]>, Observable<byte[]>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<byte[]> apply(Observable<byte[]> observable) throws Exception {
                    return observable;
                }

            })
                    .first()
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new Consumer<byte[]>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(byte[] bytes) throws Exception {
                            Log.i("Ivan1", "notification response...." + bytes.toString());
                        }

                    }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                            Log.i("Ivan", "notification response...." + throwable.toString());

                        }

                    });
```

I tried to write with rxjava1 and rxjava2, but in both cases I got a compile time error for apScanDataNotificationObservable.first(). It says "first(byte[]) in Observable cannot be applied to ()". So I dont know what argument I should pass to the first method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you get this error is because the original answer was provided for a `RxJava1` version of the `RxAndroidBle` and you are using `RxJava2` at least in the above example.

Between `RxJava1` and `RxJava2` the method `Observable.first()` has changed signature and implementation. Equivalent function for `RxJava2` is `Observable.take(int count)`

You should change this line:

```
apScanDataNotificationObservable.first(),
```

To this:

```
apScanDataNotificationObservable.take(1),
```

Also, the `Observable.combineLatest()` accepts two `Observable` parameters where `rxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic()` is a `Single`. You should change this line:

```
rxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic(RX_CHAR_UUID, getInputBytes()),
```

To this:

```
rxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic(RX_CHAR_UUID, getInputBytes()).toObservable(),
```

Comment: Thank you for response, i already tried that, and then all args insade the combineLatest then have a red line, with the message 'cannot resolve method io.reactivex.Single<byte[]>, io.reactivex.Observable<byte[]>, anonymous io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction<byte[],byte[],byte[]>)'

Comment: Added a bit of an answer above.

Comment: Thank you very much, a just needed to change other first method to take(1). It works