# How to implement synchronous task queue for RxAndroidBle

Tags: rx-java, rx-android, rxandroidble

### Summary

I use RxAndroidBle as the BLE communication framework in my project. I receive the data from the notification after writing in the following way:

```
public Observable<byte[]> requestCharacteristic(UUID notificationUuid, UUID writeUuid, byte[] writeData) {
    return Observable.zip(
             connectionObservable.concatMap(rxConnection -> rxConnection.setupNotification(notificationUuid))
                 .concatMap(rxConnection -> rxConnection).first(),
             connectionObservable.concatMap(rxConnection -> rxConnection.writeCharacteristic(writeUuid, writeData)),
             (responseBytes, writeBytes) -> { return responseBytes; }
    );
}
```

### Question

Because the BLE device needs to guarantee the synchronization request by the mobile phone, the request must be completed after the request execution is completed. I am not familiar with RX. How can I do the FIFO way to execute the above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have stated your code will work for a single execution but when there would be multiple parallel requests they will not get serialised. What you would need to add is an external synchronisation for your `requestCharacteristic()` function.

There is an already answered [question for keeping a persistant connection with serialised write/notification handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38902913/rxandroidble-keeping-a-persistant-connection-write-notification-handling/) which may be exactly what you are looking for. The answer was created for the library version that was based on `RxJava1` but it should not be too hard to adjust it to `RxJava2`.

Comment: Thanks , this way can make logical serial